# How to publish an action with tagged Google Places (or Maps)?

Tags: facebook, location, action, tagging, google-places-api

I'm having problem publishing actions (using OpenGraph) with tagged Google Places instead of Facebook Place. It should be straight forward according to the following document:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/location_tagging/#third_party

But every time I try to publish an action with **place=http://GOOGLE_PLACE_URL** I get the following error message:

**The action you're trying to publish is invalid because the specified place 'http://GOOGLE_PLACE_URL' is invalid.**

I've tried to put Google Maps, Google Places and Google+ Local URLs but all with the same problem.

Note: I could successfully publish actions when I set "place=Facebook_Place_ID".

Any help or hint is greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Google's place pages have the markup necessary to support Open Graph

From the documentation:

> Publishing actions with 3rd party places is similar to the location
>   tagging example above, except that you will pass in the url to another
>   site's `place` object.

The foursquare example in the documentation is defined as a place, as well as having the metadata foursquare uses:
https://foursquare.com/v/eataly/4c5ef77bfff99c74eda954d3

See [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)  for that URL at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Ffoursquare.com%2Fv%2Feataly%2F4c5ef77bfff99c74eda954d3 - it clearly shows that foursquare's place is defined as `‎og:type‎  playfoursquare:venue` and has location data available for Facebook - i suspect Google does not have this on their place pages

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Yes, the lack of OG markups could be the reason! But I wish the documentation mentioned this... it's very brief and simply states that one should just pass the URL and the integration is done: _Publishing actions with 3rd party places is similar to the location tagging example above, except that you will pass in the url to another site's place object._ It's not the whole truth though. At least it should mention the integration mechanism behind.

Comment: After all, I'm in wonder why Google does not provide those OG markups?! It's not just another place/map provider... Google is one of the main players here!

Comment: In the documentation you linked to (under the heading "Specifying Object Type") you can read about how to create a "third party location". https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/location_tagging/#object_type